# Meaning of a basic definition in Flask

Tags: python, class, object, flask

I'm following Miguel Grinberg's Flask Megatutorial. He defines the configuration class of the app as:

```
class Config(object):
    SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY') or 'you-will-never-guess'
```

What is te meaning of `object`? why is it passed to the classs? to my understanding, passing an argument when defining a class means inheritance so, why is `Config` inheriting form `object` and in what other cases should I do the same?

Comment: That means you're looking at an old tutorial. Dump it and find one that's more up to date. There are _very_ few valid reasons to be working with Python 2 in 2019, and you definitely shouldn't be learning it as a new language.

Comment: I like python3.6+, especially python3.8 so much~